# venv - pip not found

Tags: python, pip

- I am using **Windows 10 & Python 3.9**
- I am new to Python, after I created `venv` and facing the following errors:
- **My venv is able to catch the pip path** when I use the command `where pip`. Which is in F drive

  ```
    (venv) F:\Documents\venv\MachineLearning\venv> where pip

       F:\Documents\venv\MachineLearning\venv\Scripts\pip.exe

       C:\Users\MALARMANNAN R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe
       F:\Additional softwares\python\Python\Scripts\pip.exe
  ```
- But when I use **`pip list`** or **`pip install <package_name>`**, I am getting error : **`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'`**

  ```
    (venv) F:\Documents\venv\MachineLearning\venv>pip list

    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\MALARMANNAN R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main 
             return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
        File "C:\Users\MALARMANNAN R\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code 
             exec(code, run_globals)
        File "F:\Documents\venv\MachineLearning\venv\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
  ```

Comment: Just a little note: Try not to use screenshots. It is better to use `formatted text` ;)

Comment: will not use screenshots next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- My problem is resolved.
- Instead of using `pip install <packages>` just need to use **`python -m pip install <packages>`**, within `venv` to avoid the following error

  ```
    ModuleImportError : No module namded pip
  ```
- **These two documents helped to resolve this issue**.
- [Installing Packages using pip within venv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/)
- [Python venv : How to create, activate & delete](https://python.land/virtual-environments/virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove virtual environment and create a new one